# NetBeans library issue

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to Java , and I would like to ask about importing libraries. I'm trying to import a folder, and I can import it from

`properties ->
library ->
add jar/folder`

I'm trying to add a folder that contain multiple jar files, but I can't find any sense in the "Add Folder" option, because I'm unable to use the classes that exist in that folder. 
How do I add a folder and use all the classes or .jars it contains?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to creating `Netbeans Library`

1. Select Tools -> Ant Libraries
2. Select "New Library"
3. Provide new library name
4. Add Jars

Once you create library you can select that library in your projects.

Comment: you mean add JAR/folder does not make any sense if I add folder ?? and it does not have useful usage ?? @vels4j

Comment: U can add jars individually or folder in nb project libraries. Folder I used for images,property files etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "lib" folder under your project and contain all your jars there.

Comment: you means that add folder does not make any sense , no use for add folder ??